# How to find similar images on the RFCN model in the tensorflow library?

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, tensorflow

I am doing a deep learning report that specifically uses the tensorflow library to identify and target the subject, and I want to find the same image as the identifying image, what should I do?

I have a tutorial on [identifying images similar](http://douglasduhaime.com/posts/identifying-similar-images-with-tensorflow.html) to the CNN model but with RFCN (**rfcn_resnet101_coco**) I have not done it yet. May everyone help.

Thank you very much

Comment: I believe this question is a bit broad. Are you asking how to implement the RFCN model using tensorflow?

Comment: I want to find similar images in the RFCN model, you show me how to do it? Thanks very much

Comment: What have you tried so far?